# How to upload very large JPGs to Media Library for WooCommerce digital download prints

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, media-library

I'm trying to upload a JPG `9927 px x 14043 px` through editing a WooCommerce product, and adding a downloadable file. Every time I try, I Receive an error:

> Post-processing of the image failed likely because the server is busy
> or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help.
> Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.

There is plenty of disk space (`20 GB`).

I've CHMOD all directories from /wp-content onwards to 755, but the issue remains.

The PHP `max_upload_size` is `128MB`, and the images are no more than `35MB` in size.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Various web server timeouts can be the cause of this problem. Can you try to do it via WP CLI [`wp media import`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/import/)?

Comment: It's not necessarily a question of disk space or upload size, but memory and processing power to create image sizes without timing out. You should speak to your host about making more resources available.